How can jni be leveraged for an abstract class?
I am just getting familiar with jni/java and the workflow where we want to invoke methods that are written in native code but what i am unable to understand yet is how JNI can be leveraged if the native C++ library have a C++ abstract class like below which can both be inherited by C++ to create concrete C++ classes but can also be extended by java class
class NumberInterface {
public:

    using Numbers = std::unordered_set<unsigned int>;
 
    /**
     * Getter to receive all numbers.
     *
     * @return Numbers.
     */
    virtual Numbers getSupportedNumbers() = 0;
 
    virtual bool handleNumber(unsigned int number) = 0;
    virtual bool cancelNumber(unsigned int number) = 0;
 
};

So if this is a shared library than on the native side, some library can link to it and it can have have a number class like below
class Number : public NumberInterface {
public:
    Numbers getSupportedNumbers() override;
 
    bool handleNumber(unsigned int number) override;
    bool cancelNumber(unsigned int number) override;
...
};

what what i am not able to figure out so far is that on the Java side, if i have a library/apk that needs to consume this native utility library , how can i structure my utility or jni such that we can have a java class that can extends NumberInterface.
class JavaNumber extends JavaNumberInterfaceEquivalent {
...
}

----edited to add move code snippet---
i want the util class to also have a NumberManagerInterface like below
/// NumberManagerInterface that can handle numbers.
class NumberInterface {
public:
 
    /**
     * Register modules that handle numbers.
     *
     * @return true if successful, false otherwise.
     */
    virtual bool registerNumberModule(const std::shared_ptr<NumberModuleInterface>& module) = 0;
 
    virtual bool handleNumber(const unsigned int number) = 0;
    virtual bool cancelNumber(const unsigned int number) = 0;
 
};

/**
 * Sample NumberManager class.
 *
 */
class NumberManager : public NumberManagerInterface{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<NumberManagerInterface> createNumberManagerInstance(...);
    bool registerNumberModule(const std::shared_ptr<NumberModuleInterface>& module) override;
    bool handleNumber(const unsigned int number) override;
    bool cancelNumber(const unsigned int number) override;
    ...
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<NumberModuleInterface>> m_numberHandlers;
    ...
};

bool NumberManager::registerNumberModule(const std::shared_ptr<NumberModuleInterface>& module){
     // do some validation
     m_numberHandlers.insert(module);
     ...
     return true;
}
 
bool NumberManager::handleNumber(const unsigned int number){
  //find the correct handler from m_numberHandlers
  //call the correct handler
  return handler->handleNumber(number);
}
 
void NumberManager::cancelNumber(const unsigned int number){
...
}


You can't, jni doesn't support c++ classes, you'd have to implement your derived class in c++ and have that call into Java

You can create a Java class that extends the C++ NumberInterface using JNI, allowing you to call native functions from your Java code. check this link https://github.com/google/jni-bind

JNI only supports to make functions native. The class itself remains a Java class.

So if i understand correctly @AlanBirtles, you are suggesting that the only way is to have a c++ library consume the native util library and that library have a derived class and we than expose that class methods in Java side using JNI, is the understanding correct, one issue i do see is that the Java class would be making some Java specific API's call using IPC so i do not think this will work.

The idea is to have a common util where both Java and C++ developers can register for Number Classes and than there will be a NumberManager that will have a list of all these Number classes and knows which specific number class to execute based on the input number.

@BobSmith i would have to check this jni-bind, not familiar with it, but seems like based on your comment above Java class can extend from C++ NumberInterface , or am i missing something here.

@Robert although i am still getting familiar with jni, but so far and as you have mentioned as well  only finding support to make some java function native. just fyi Bob above did mention that Java class might extend C++ interfaces through jni-bind but i still need to look into that.

Maybe what i am trying to achieve here is not possible the way i am visualizing it and i need to come up with something different for this utility for Java/C++ support.

By the way, JEP 454: Foreign Function & Memory API

@bourne First, you'll need a JNI header file (.h) that defines the native methods corresponding to the C++ NumberInterface then create a Java class that extends NumberInterfaceEquivalent then implement the native methods in your C++ code using JNI.

@BobSmith JNI doesn't support extending C++ class in Java. What you suggest seems to be create a wrapper but is not real inheritance.

@aled yes you are right but the way I suggested will solve the problem of bourne.

@BobSmith so i updated and added more code to indicate what i had in mind, so apart from NumberInterface i also have a NumberManager create method that can be invoked through Java using jni. So if i understand you correctly are you suggesting that i have something like this
abstract class NumberInterfaceEquivalent {     public abstract Numbers getSupportedNumbers();     public abstract boolean handleNumber(long number);     public abstract boolean cancelNumber(long number); }
and than i will have a Java class extend that and it will call the native method internally using jni.

Calling the NumberManager from Java is straightforward: define a Java class with some native methods and plumb the arguments through.
Providing Java implementations of NumberInterface is more involved.
On the Java side, we define an interface:
// java
interface NumberInterface {
  long[] getSupportedNumbers();
  void handleNumber(long);
  void cancelNumber(long);
  static native void registerNumberInterface(NumberInterface);
}

we use long here because Java does not have unsigned integers.
We can define the wrapper like so:
class JavaNumberInterface : public NumberInterface {
  public:
  JavaNumberInterface(jobject o) {
    JNIEnv *env = getEnv();
    obj = env->NewGlobalRef(o);
  }

  Numbers getSupportedNumbers() override {
    JNIEnv *env = getEnv();
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getSupportedNumbers", "()[J");

    jlongArray jarr = (jlongArray) env->CallObjectMethod(obj, mid);
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(jarr);
    jlong* arr = env->GetLongArrayElements(jarr, nullptr);

    Numbers ret;
    for (auto x: std::span(arr, len)) {
      ret.insert(int(x));
    }
    env->ReleaseLongArrayElements(jarr, arr, JNI_ABORT);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(jarr);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
    return ret;
  }
 
  bool handleNumber(unsigned int number) override { /* similar */ }
  bool cancelNumber(unsigned int number) override { /* similar */ }

  private:
    jobject obj;
    JNIEnv *getEnv();
};

The native implementation of registerNumberInterface is then:
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NumberInterface_registerNumberInterface(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject obj) {
  NumberManager& nm = getNumberManagerSomehow();
  nm.registerNumberModule(std::make_shared<JavaNumberInterface>(obj));
}

